# Magento 1.9 - Error getChildHtml with content Javascript

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, phtml

I tried to insert a `getChildHtml` in view.phtml file but half page is empty. The file that i would insert is a file with `javascript/php/html` code otherwise if i insert only html or php code the file is showing.

So...i declared my block in `catalog.xml` in this way:

```
block type="page/block"  name="product.info.calculator" as="calculator" template="catalog/product/view/calculator.phtml"
```

and in the view.phtml:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('calculator');
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: in catalog.xml where did you add your code? under what reference ?

Comment: In Product view...in <catalog_product_view translate="label"> this is the position: <reference name="content"><block type="page/block"  name="product.info.calculator" as="calculator" template="catalog/product/view/calculator.phtml"/>
                <block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" /></reference>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how it should be:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <!-- Will show with out control on the product page -->
    </reference>

    <reference name="product.info">
        <!-- you can call it anywhere in the page using getChildHtml -->
    </reference>

</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: I tried man but my getChildHtml not working. I show the content of file only i write in html and in php. If i past javascript code the result is the same. Half page is empty. Others possible solutions? Thank you.

Comment: so you are saying the getChildHtml works but when you add javascript to your file it doesn't work? -- I'm happy to help but I need to understand

Comment: Exactly! Update: I saw that the problem is when i declare a variable on javascript, for example: <script type="text/javascript">var prezzo = "<?php echo ($_product->getFinalPrice());?>"...

Comment: this will not work!!! you need to get the product collection in your file first. add this before your code $_product = Mage::registry('current_product');

Comment: Man you're great!!! Now works!!! Thank you very much!!!! ;)

Comment: :) happy to help